# Why did the foreground color turn red

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to install Synergy on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, found out it is not compatible with Wayland so rebooted with Xorg and the foreground color changed to red cloud covering everything.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy doens't support Wayland yet. So you used Xorg. What you need to do is go into your display settings and remove the color profile and select the standard RGB profile. You can try other profiles as you please. That will correct the issue.

Keep in mind also, that Synergy doesn't work for the login screen by default, so you will need to do auto-login or configure the xorg to load Synergy before it starts. It does work on the lock screen though, after your first log in. Otherwise you will still need to use a keyboard for it.